# Django-Rest-Framework browsable API not showing 'editable=False' fields within the POST box

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I would like to be able to instantiate my `Job` entities via the browsable API (of django-rest-framework), however my employer field has the field `editable=False`. Therefore the employer entry box does not appear.

This is what I see when editable=False (code further below):
[(Image) POST form without employer entry box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3yQ9.png)

This is what I see when I remove editable=False (code further below):
[(Image) POST form with employer entry box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JorU0.png)

How can I get employer box to show whilst not allowing the employer field not to be changed after it is first set? (So that it will look like the second image)

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from users.models import Proof_User

class Job(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=False, null=False)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    employer = models.ForeignKey(Proof_User, editable=False, related_name='jobs', blank=False, null=False)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class Job_Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Job
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'description', 'employer',)
```

**views.py**

```
class Job_Viewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Job.objects.all()
    serializer_class = Job_Serializer
```

Comment: See the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34528153/1571826) for a good explanation of why you don't see the field, and how you could display it.